# Setting the cursor position within a TextItem in SmartGWT

Tags: gwt, smartgwt

I'm using a TextItem in SmartGWT and I want to update the cursor position in that text field when a user clicks on some button. 
Is that possible?

In general, is there a text field widget that is not part of the form package in SmartGWT?

Thanks!

Comment: There is only the TextItem which can be put inside the SmartGWT DynamicForm. You can try to use the TextBox that comes along with GWT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use TextItem.setSelectionRange() with start and end the same.

http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwtee/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/TextItem.html#setSelectionRange%28int,%20int%29